# iOS: Vertically Printing All Days In a Month

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, nsdate, nscalendar

So I'm trying trying to print all the days in a month, vertically on a UIScrollView. Here is a mock-up in photoshop of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSRange nums = [cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:[NSDate date]];
NSUInteger numberOfDaysInMonth = nums.length;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numberOfDaysInMonth];
```

Now this is the code I have so far, it finds what month it is then it counts the number of days in the current month. So my problem is I'm really lost on how to print them like I did in my design. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you could use a `UITableview` and a custom cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to Paulw11, he suggested that I use a UITableview. I can't believe I didn't think of that.